# Add the word "cook" or "cooking" to the site description on Stack Exchange sites list

Tags: feature-request

I was looking for a cooking SE site a few times in the last years, and I just found it this week - how come?
I searched the words *food / cook* in the [Stack Exchange All Sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic) list, and not for the word *chef*.

In the full sites list, the description is:

> Q&A for professional and amateur chefs

And in the [site tour](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tour), the description is:

> **Seasoned Advice** is a site for professional and amateur cooks and chefs, and anyone who works in the kitchen or is interested in preparing and serving delicious meals.

I think it would be much easier to find the existence of the site if the former description will be changed to this: (similarly to the tour description)

> Q&A for professional and amateur cooks and chefs

Comment: Sounds good to me.  cooking.stackexchge.com is an alias to the site